# Moving Tridion Library to GAC

Tags: 2011

We are planning to move all Tridion DLL from the website's BIN directory to computers' Global Assembly Cache (GAC) so they don't need to be repeated for each website. Is there anything I should pay attention to? Any downside of doing so?

Comment: This isn't a question specific about Tridion, rather is a generic GAC vs. App's bin question.  It should be asked on Stackoverflow and not be specific to Tridion.

Comment: Nick - I don't think so. For example, what if this affects the support position... etc. I'd say it's a reasonable question to ask in a Tridion context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agreed it is not strictly Tridion specific but in Tridion context, I would say:

- Do not do that on the production (stating the obvious), but do some testing / try and error on Dev box
- When later on upgrading Tridion and site, do not forget GAC has old version of dlls
- When a new Tridion DLL happens to have the same assembly version (but a different file version), the GAC version will be picked up even if you have a local BIN copy.
- Make sure any interop and juggernet related dll work without a local BIN copy
- If it is a dev machine, put the DLLs in a sensible and easy to remember place so Visual Studio can refer to them.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a post discussing putting assemblies in GAC vs. BIN:
http://www.instantquick.com/index.php/deploying-assemblies-to-bin-versus-gac?c=elumenotion-blog-archive/features

It is no different for Tridion.